# Would somebody like to create a "wiktionary" tag please?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-creation

There are currently [77 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiktionary) on SO dealing with [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org) but as yet there's no tag.

Since I'm still a ways of the reputation necessary could somebody else create [wiktionary](/questions/tagged/wiktionary) if they also deem it a good tag candidate please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiktionary](/questions/tagged/wiktionary) tag now exists. Feel free to go retag some questions when appropriate.